# Do salt lamps really produce negative ions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, air, ions

Do [salt lamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Himalayan_salt#Salt_Lamps) really produce negative ions? Do you know about any scientific study that could support this assertion or disprove it?

Comment: Phrased as it is, i.e. essentially a reference request, I guess this would fit better on [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/)…

Comment: @truthseeker: do you want a hard reference or a scientific explanation from anyone?

Comment: @F'x anyways, I'll mark it for migration.

Comment: I dislike this question because it implies that 'negative ions' are something special and exotic, and that salt crystals might also be special and exotic.  It's just a hunk of salt and an incandescent lamp!

Comment: @nibot: 'negative ions' are special and exotic to almost everybody outside of science and engineering.

Comment: Negative ions of what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no study because there is no physical mechanism were a salt crystal sends negative ions into the air without any energy input. Just heating the inside up with an incandescent lamp warms the lamp a bit but this does not create any measurable amount of negative ions.

There are [ion generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_ioniser) but these work on a completely different principle. Basically you need a very high electric field to ionize air molecules or dust particles. Here is a [study](http://aaqr.org/VOL11_No2_April2011/9_AAQR-10-06-OA-0048_179-186.pdf) that explains how the air quality is positively influenced by a air purifier that creates negative ions.

Comment: Absence of proof vs. proof of absence… I agree with your answer for the physics, but there could be a study (and there probably is, somewhere) aimed at demonstrating that indeed, salt lamps heated with an incandescent lamp do not yield negative ions.

Comment: @F'x: I think it's quite unlikely. A scientific study is work- and time consuming and who would want to fund such an endeavour and it is hard to prove a negative anyway.

Comment: Mechanism: "Some salt lamp manufacturers claim that the natural absorption of moisture and its subsequent release through the heating effect of the lamp, releases negative ions. Is this a fact?"

Comment: @endolith: If a salt crystal becomes wet there will be a solution of Cl- and Na+ ions in water at the surface. The evaporation of Cl- ions in a water droplet is possible, that the whole droplet is negatively charged still unlikely. Reductio ad absurdum: A pot of boiling salt water would create a gigantic amount of negative ions.

Answer (score 1):

This website addresses this issue. I have no idea how rigorous it is but it is interesting.
http://www.negativeionsinformation.org/saltcrystallamps.html